# Set TTL (Time to live) on CFS files

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I am storing files in cassandra files system (CFS) but the number of files will grow over period of time. Need to delete older files automatically . Is there way to set TTL on cfs at file level or keyspace level?

Answer (score 0):

You can only define a TTL clause [only per column or table level](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useExpire.html). When you are setting it, some of the things that you need to consider are:

- The space may be reclaimed once that the **TTL** and the **gc_grace_seconds** passed; the default for gc_grace_seconds is 10 days.
- The process that will free the space is a **compaction**, which have different behaviours depending on the compaction stragey defined for the table. You can force a compaction with the command ***nodetool compact***; more information about its execution is available [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-arch/datastax_enterprise/dbInternals/dbIntHowDataMaintain.html).
- Once that you altered the table, with the **default_time_to_live** clause, the TTL will be applied to new data after it is specified; for the existing data you will need to reinsert all of it; optionally you can define a different value for the ttl, but you'll need to consider that as Cassandra has an append-only approach, you will have a temporary increase of disk usage; because of this, before applying a TTL, you may need to evaluate scaling up the cluster if disk space is already a constraint.